# More efficient way than array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am suppose to emulate what memory looks like in a system.

My teacher will enter at least 1MB of memory in words.

Assuming every word is 2 bytes that would be 524288 words.

Instead of making an array to hold such a large value. What would be an easier way than creating an array that looks like    int  MemorySize[524288];

Is there a more efficient way?

And why im asking is because he will enter the size of the memory, then he will input the size of processes and how much memory they take. So i need a way to distuingish the size of them.

So if he enters that the total memory size is 524288 words which is 1MB.

And then he enters two processes that are half a meg each, how can i distuingish that without having a spew of numbers in an array?

Comment: My main issue is not wasting so much ram and having my program crash.

Comment: I don't really understand how you're "emulating" memory. But I think what you want is a separate table to keep track of where processes start and their size, then just use an array of bytes.

Comment: And so i dont have a stackoverflow lol

Comment: So basically convert the words into an array of bytes?

Comment: Yes but see the answer and use either the `new` keyword (C++) or the C `malloc` function so that you allocate on the heap (and not the stack).

Comment: Wont converting 500,000 words turn it into double those values into an array? Making it twice as bad?

Comment: If your teacher is going to put in 1MB of data, you need at least 1MB of space. Whether that's split up into bytes or words, it's still 1MB of space.

Comment: I put an array in my program with 500,000 entries and it crashed.

Comment: That's nice. If you give more information about what you've tried, what errors you get, and what you think might be wrong you might be able to get some help with that.

Comment: I think your teacher wants to teach you [Virtual Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). You can make a translation table (initialized with all NULLs) with fixed sector size `4KB` or something and double indirect pointers and allocate pages using malloc only when the pages are required. You can even make this memory fixed size and keep swapping pages with files if all pages extinct.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `malloc(N)` if you want to allocate memory of N bytes; if you want W words of 2 bytes each, simply do `malloc(2*W)`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question here is though.